# Evaluation of named entity recognition

Tags: named-entity-recognition

I am a newbie to Named Entity Recognition (NER). In one of my projects, for the purpose of evaluating I calculated the precision, recall and f-measure values of NER.

Are there any recognized standard threshold values for precision, recall and f-measure of NER from which we can evaluate how good the NER service is?